# Why am I getting errors when trying to use plot() in R to create a boxplot?

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I'm trying to create a very simple boxplot for some data. My professor told us to the use the plot() function, not boxplot(), although neither work.

Here's the head of my data:

```
Wage Educ Exper Age Male Generation

1 37.85   11     2  40    1      Older

2 21.72    4     1  39    0    Younger

3 14.34    4     2  38    0    Younger

4 21.26    5     9  53    1      Older

5 24.65    6    15  59    1      Older

6 25.65    6    12  36    1    Younger
```

I'm supposed to create a boxplot with Generation in the x axis and Wage in the y axis. I feel like this should be really simple but I keep getting errors. Here's my code:

```
> plot(wages$Generation,wages$Wage)

Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values

In addition: Warning messages:

1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion

2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

It just returns a blank white screen. There seems to be some issue with the "Generation" column which I added in R, it wasn't originally part of the dataset. It returns a weird message if I try to attach the data:

```
> attach(wages)
The following object is masked _by_ .GlobalEnv:

    Generation
```

Any help is appreciated, you can probably tell I'm really new to R.

Comment: Maybe that column is character type? Try `plot(as.factor(wages$Generation), wages$Wage)`

Comment: @Suren that worked! Thank you so much, this was killing me!

Comment: Not related to your issue but some advice: don't use `attach`. It causes [problems](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2011/05/to-attach-or-not-attach-that-is-the-question/).

Comment: @neilfws I had no idea, thanks!